# jQuery/PHP Send email on mousedown link event

Tags: php, jquery, sendmail

Here my code. I could not display errors message. Simply mail is not sent. What's wrong with this approach ?

```
        <a id="target" href="http://www.mylink.wav">mylink</a>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {
            $("#target").mousedown(function() {
                $.post(
                    "sendemail.php",
                    { name: "John" }
                );
            });
        });

    </script>

<?php

if($_POST)
{

    $mail = "myemail.email.com"
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = 'My subject';

    $to = "myemail@email.com";

    $message = "My message: ".$name."<br />";

    $headers = "From: $mail \n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $mail \n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 \n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 \n";

}

?>
```

Thank you for your suggestions to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly check if you actually are calling your script inside jQuery block.

Second, you need to include php `mail()` function (if enabled on server):

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php